# Как сделать корректный выбор загрузки на ПК, на которых есть Windows ХР и две ОС Windows 10

Tags: windows

Доброе время суток,
Такая ситуация: есть 2 HDD, на каждом из которых установлены *Windows XP* и *Windows 10* (при загрузке есть выбор этих ОС), я добавил/поставил SSD.
Поставил вторую *Windows 10* на SSD.
Результат:
Теперь при загрузке систем нужно использовать «*F8*» и выбирать:

```
- HDD, при котором у меня появляется выбор ОС, между Windows ХР и Windows 10.
- HDD, при котором просто загружается вторая Windows 10.
```

Вопрос:
Можно ли избежать использовать «*F8*» и сразу выходить на выбор трех ОС:
- «Windows ХР»
- «Windows 10»
- «Windows 10»
?

Спасибо.

Comment: Экий зоопарк Вы себе организовали на свою голову.

Comment: Тут все зависит от особенностей материнской платы, версии биоса и даже о подверсии Виндовс 10. Если Вы хотите сделать все по-феншую, надо курить интернет на тему Grub, EasyUEFI, diskpart, bcdedit, bcdboot, Partition Assistant. Причем эти утилиты настолько суровые, что "одно неловкое движение, и.." можно легко выстрелить себе в ногу. Причем и железо, и софт в этой области дикой анархии изобилуют трудноуловимыми багами.

Comment: Воспользовался утилитой "easybcd" (как говорят для чайников ),   
1,5 минуты и все отлично работает... Только вот у меня меню выбора ОС опять превратилось с плиточно-голубого (стандартного) на черный например такой https://www.dropbox.com/s/r8yzfs879y2qc1d/3%20OS.jpg?dl=0 и
"*bcdedit /set {default} bootmenupolicy standard*" **не** помог